How to properly send array of objects with MockMvc POST api request which controller using @ModelAttribute?
I try to write post API endpoint test with MockMvc that send multiple parameters including array of objects and I got this error.

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<201> but was:<400>

with no error message (null) from MockHttpServletResponse.
I think the problem is about sending array of objects which request param model define it as List<Map<String, Object>> but I can't figure it out how to solve the problem.
Here is what I try.
Request body :
{
  "study_class_id": 1,
  "lecture_values": [
    {
      "topic": 1,
      "content": "Lorem ipsum"
    },
    {
      "topic": 2,
      "content": "Lorem ipsum"
    }
  ]
}


Controller :
@PostMapping(value = "/lecture")
public ResponseEntity<LecturesResource> addLecture(
    @Valid @ModelAttribute("Lecture") LectureAddRequestParam param,
    BindingResult bindingResult, Principal principal, HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) {

    return processResult;
}

Request param model :
public class LectureAddRequestParam {

  @NotNull
  @Min(1)
  private int study_class_id;

  @NotNull
  private List<Map<String, Object>> lecture_values;
 
  // Getter Setter..
}

POST api endpoint test :
// Prepare lecture values param
JSONObject lecture1 = new JSONObject();
lecture1.put("topic", 1);
lecture1.put("content", "Lorem ipsum");

JSONObject lecture2 = new JSONObject();
lecture2.put("topic", 2);
lecture2.put("content", "Lorem ipsum");

JSONArray lectureValues = new JSONArray();
lectureValues.add(lecture1);
lectureValues.add(lecture2);

var responseContent = mockMvc
    .perform(
        post("/lecture")
            .with(csrf())
            .param("study_class_id", Integer.toString(studyClassId))
            .param("lecture_values", lectureValues.toString()))
            .andDo(log())
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andReturn()
            .getResponse()
            .getContentAsString();

Request call is success with jQuery ajax :
$.ajax({
  url: '/lecture',
  type: 'POST',
  timeout: this.TIMEOUT_LIMIT,
  headers: requestHeader,
    data: {
      study_class_id: study_class_id,
      lecture_values: lecture_values.toJSON()
    }
});

the reason here using toJSON() is because it is Backbone.js collection.
I've also tried with flashAttr. I create lectureJSONObject that contain

int study_class_id
json array objects of lecture_values

flashAttr("lecture", lectureJSONObject)

And tried creating Lecture class that contain

int study_class_id
List<Map<String, Object>> lecture_values
by convert jsonarray object to  List<Map<String, Object>>

flashAttr("lecture", lectureObject)

add send it with flashAttr but both are not working and there's no error message.
